# How does the mask work in the Transformer if it receives a batch of different sentences as input?

Tags: deep-learning

I'm currently working on a PyTorch implementation of the Transformer model and had a question.

Right now, I've coded my model so that it receives source and target sentence pairs as batches. These sentences are encoded using their respective indices from a pre-made vocabulary. For example:

```
[[3,  2,  1, 23, 13, 50, 541, 0],
 [3, 24, 13,  0,  0,  0,   0, 0],
 [3, 98,  2,  4,  1,  23, 25, 4]]
```

where `0` are the padding indices.

My question is regarding how we should use the masking mechanism for these sentences if they're being fed in as batches. I suppose the reason why I'm confused is because I'm aware that the mask look something like:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

so that we can force our Decoder to only attend to the next sequence. Do we apply this mask iteratively to the same sentence as we run the model? For example, if we were to use the first sentence I gave above:

```
# Iteration 1
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

# Iteration 2
[3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

.
.
.
```

and so we'd obtain a prediction at each position, for each sentence in each batch?

Answer (score 1):

Your decoder batch mask is a lower triangular mask (which you have), element-wise and'ed with a pad mask which is true where your caption isn't a pad value. Here's some toy code (mostly taken from https://github.com/SamLynnEvans/Transformer) for generating such a mask, with an example:

```
import numpy as np
import torch

def lower_triangular_mask(size):
    """
    Create a lower triangular mask
    """

    lt_mask = np.triu(np.ones((1, size, size)), k=1)
    lt_mask = torch.from_numpy(lt_mask) == 0

    return lt_mask

def create_mask(caption, pad_value):
    """
    Creates the transformer decode mask
    """

    # create pad mask
    pad_mask = (caption != pad_value).unsqueeze(-2)

    # create lower triangular mask
    size = caption.size(1)
    lt_mask = lower_triangular_mask(size)

    # return the bitwise AND of the two masks
    return pad_mask & lt_mask

if __name__ == '__main__':
    torch.manual_seed(0)

    # Here, we generate some random sequences, with an assigned pad value of 1
    pad_value = 1
    caption = torch.randint(2, 10, size=(2, 5))
    caption[0, 3] = pad_value
    caption[0, 4] = pad_value

    print(caption)

    mask = create_mask(caption, pad_value)
    print(mask.size())
    print(mask)
```

The above code returns

```
tensor([[6, 9, 7, 1, 1],
        [5, 5, 9, 3, 5]])
torch.Size([2, 5, 5])
tensor([[[ True, False, False, False, False],
         [ True,  True, False, False, False],
         [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
         [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
         [ True,  True,  True, False, False]],

        [[ True, False, False, False, False],
         [ True,  True, False, False, False],
         [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]]])
```

The first caption, which is shorter than the second, results in a mask which doesn't let the transformer attend past the end of its sequence.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have two separate types of masking in the encoder and in the decoder.

Your encoder performs self-attention and so it needs to mask pad tokens. This way real tokens don't attend to pad tokens. If your input is of shape `B x T x D`, then your mask needs to be of shape `B x T x T`. That means that for each and every sequence in the batch you have a separate mask.

Your decoder performs ***causal*** self-attention and so for a given token it needs to mask all of the tokens that come after it. This means that the mask will be the same for all of the sequences in the batch - a simple lower-triangular matrix of shape `T x T`.

Here is an image showing padding masks and the causal mask.

[image: mask]

Here is an extensive [blog post](https://pi-tau.github.io/posts/transformer/) that I wrote about the Transformer, you might like it.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused about the decoder mask for a while. And I found out the confusion came from misunderstanding of the training of Transformers.

Just like other seq2seq models, a Transformer predicts one token after another iteratively during *inference*.

**But when it's *training*, it predicts the whole sequence at once!**

Let's recap self-attention. The attention weight matrix A = softmax(QK^T / sqrt(d_k)):

[image: Attention weight matrix]

Each row of the matrix represents the attention weight of a token to all other tokens.

After applying the weight matrix to the values, we get the output of the attention layer X = AV. The output is of the same length as the input sequence and it can be regarded as the output of the encoder (if the number of layers is 1 and the feed-forward sub-layer is an identity function).

See! predicting the whole sequence at once!

The decoder has the same story except we don't want it to peek at the ground truth and future tokens during training.

**Because the decoder gets the target sequence (ignoring shift for simplicity) as input during training and is expected to output the same target sequence.**

When it's computing the ith output token X[i], we modify the ith row of the attention weight matrix A[i] to zero out the weight to the ith and all future tokens. Now X[i] is computed based on the tokens before the ith position only.

So the ith row of the decoder mask works on the ith output token. And all output tokens are predicted at once during training. That's why Transformers can be trained so efficiently.